# python-chess returns "none" when the score is like "-M8"

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, python-chess

I'm using python 3.6 with Jupyter and Anaconda.
The script goes move by move in a chess game from a PGN file, and it returns a score. That works great.

The problem comes when the score returned is "-M8", which means black can give checkmate in 8 moves.

But the following line:

```
(handler.info["score"][1].cp)
```

returns "none" instead of "-M8" as expected.

Script:

```
import chess
import chess.uci
import chess.pgn
import sys

with open('E:\PGN Files\Fischer.pgn') as f:


    handler = chess.uci.InfoHandler()
    engine = chess.uci.popen_engine('C:\Program Files (x86)\Arena\Engines\stockfish_9_x64.exe') #give correct address of your engine here
    engine.info_handlers.append(handler)

    for number in range(10):
        game = chess.pgn.read_game(f)
        m=0
        while not game.is_end():
            m=m+1
            node = game.variations[0]
            board = game.board() 

            game = node         

            engine.position(board)

            #Set your evaluation time, in ms:
            evaltime = 5000 #so 5 seconds
            evaluation = engine.go(movetime=evaltime)

            score =(handler.info["score"][1].cp)
            print(str(score))
```

Comment: `open('E:\\PGN Files\\Fischer.pgn')` and same for the Popen argument, no need to `str(score)` because that is exactly what `print` will do anyway

Comment: sorry about my english, beside that, do you know why the engine or python returns none instead of the "-M8"??

Comment: The engine runs in a separate process, you need to wait 5 seconds or use a custom handler.

Comment: `.cp` is for centi pawn value, if mate, the score s not in centi pawn. Try a keyword like `.mate`, or check the `handler.info["score"]` information.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the score is somewhere, but this is a way to get the score and the score and the mate:

```
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci('C:\Program Files (x86)\Arena\Engines\stockfish_9_x64.exe', timeout = 1000.0)
evaltime = 5000 #so 5 seconds
scoreinfo = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(time = evaltime))["score"]
cp = scoreinfo.relative.score(mate_score=1000000)
if scoreinfo.is_mate():
    if scoreinfo.turn == chess.WHITE:
        mate = 1000000 - cp
    elif scoreinfo.turn == chess.BLACK:
        mate = 1000000 + cp
```